# After Login still "login" in the URL

Tags: php, url, request

The structure of my website looks like this:

- Use Clean-URL's (all requests are send to the index.php)
- At first the Login-page will showed
- If you Logged-in successful then you will be forwarded to the Home-page (home.php included).

And here is the problem:
If you will be forwarded to the Home-page, then in the URL you see still "blabla.../login".
Only if you now refresh the site, then the URL change correctly to "blabla.../home".

My question is:
After the checkLogin-method was successful, how i can "send" a request to the server?

For example:
I need something like this:

```
    <a href="home"></>
```

Comment: i think you can find an answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Answer (score 0):

User `header` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
header("Location: home");
exit();
```

Comment: I think the OP's question is a tricky/unclear one. I've read it over 10 times and still can't wrap my head around - *"For example: I need something like this: `<a href="home"></>`" --- *"And here is the problem: If you will be forwarded to the Home-page, then in the URL you see still "blabla.../login". Only if you now refresh the site, then the URL change correctly to "blabla.../home"."* - Seems like OP is (already) using redirection.

Comment: @ Jay: The problem is, that the header() can only be used, if i don't sent any HTML-stuff before. But at the moment where the checkLogin()-method is called, i sent already the wole login-page...

Comment: Then we do not have enough information to solve your issue @krokvskrok